# Set that can written as a cartesian product of subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine  with  proper Justification  which of the following    subsets  of $\mathbb{R}^3 $ can be  written as   a  cartesian  product   of   subset  of $\mathbb{R}$

$1.)$ $\{ (x_1 , x_2  , x_3 )  : x_2 = x_3 \}$

$2.)$ $\{ (x_1 , x_2  , x_3 )  : x_i \  \ge  i \ \forall  i= 1,2,3  \}$

My attempt :  I thinks   option $1$  can not   be  written as   a  cartesian  product   of a  subset  of $\mathbb{R}$ because  $x_2-x_3 =0$ this  implies  that here $x_1=0$ and  $x_2  - x_3$ is  a  subset  of $\mathbb{R}^2$

For  option $2$  $x_1 \ge 1$, $x_2 \ge  2$, $x_3 \ge 3$, this  implies  that  this  will be  a  subset  of  $\mathbb{R}^3$

Here im confused that  How can we  find  subsets  of $\mathbb{R}^3 $ that  can be  written as   a  cartesian  product   of a  subset  of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't understand, there is nothing after 2.)

Comment: @Math1000  oks  im edits

Comment: Why does it imply $x_1=0$? The question is whether you can find subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that your set can be seen to be equal to $A\times B\times C$ (at least, that’s how I interpret the question). Your comments on 1 fail to address this at all. Your comment son 2 just say “it’s a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$”, but we already knew that; that is not the question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks  u  but   $x_1  $ coordinate is not given  so  i take  $x_1 =0$

Comment: I still see nothing after 2.) Perhaps it is a problem with my browser? Edit: yes, it was my browser, apparently.

Comment: No, that’s wrong. If there are no conditions listed on $x_1$, that means that $x_1$ can be **anything**, not that it has to be equal to $0$.

Comment: ..@ArturoMagidin  sir  give  me  some  hints   about  option $1 $, as  im not  getting  how  to contradicts  the option $1$

Comment: It depends on what is expected. If you are expected to get it as a product of three sets, then note that $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are in the set; that tells you that if the set were for the form $A\times B\times C$, then you would have to have  both $0$ and $1$ in $B$ and in $C$; can you then get an element in $A\times B\times C$ that is not in your set?

Comment: yaa @ArturoMagidin Sir  Now  got  its  thanks u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 is $[1,\infty)\times[2,\infty)\times[3,\infty) $.

Comment: thanks u @Matthew  sir     what about  option $1$

Comment: Well, that is what I thought... but it says **a** subset of $\mathbb R$, not multiple subsets???

Comment: @GEdgar  i have  edits  its

Comment: Why not get it exactly right?  It is still not grammatical  Are you copying it from somewhere?  "Determine with proper justification" sure sounds like it..

Comment: @GEdgar The question may well actually read "can be written as a cartesian product of **subsets** of $\mathbb R$, in which case this would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @Math1000   what about option  $1$  any hints ?